# Delete a file using luacode

Tags: luatex, auxiliary-files, luacode

I would like to delete a file called `\jobname.someext` which is in the same directory of my `.tex` file, at the beginning of a typesetting. I know the `shellesc` package, but can I do this with a `luacode` ?

Comment: I'd use a wrapper script that does the cleanup, instead of building it into the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.remove`  This typesets

> YES
>
> NO

as the file is removed between the two calls to `\IfFileExists`

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.zzz}
whatever
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\IfFileExists{\jobname.zzz}{YES}{NO}

\directlua{os.remove('\jobname.zzz')}


\IfFileExists{\jobname.zzz}{YES}{NO}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I used `\directlua` here as I usually find it's easier but you can use the `luacode` package wrappers around this if you prefer.